# A program ran in a program

Tags: java

I was feeling bored with nothing to do (well, sort of) and decided to write a program that runs a program in Java. What it pretty much does:

1. Creates a new file with the name `classname + ".java"`
2. Write the code into that file
3. if it is not already compiled, run `javac filename.java` on the command line
4. run `java filename` on the command line

The code is below:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

/**
 * Represents some Java source code.
 * 
 * <p>
 * This source code then can be ran via the {@link #run()} method, or can be
 * just used as a storage for source code.
 * </p>
 */
public class JavaCode {

    private static final String JAVA = ".java";
    private static final String CLASS = ".class";
    private static final String COMPILE = "javac ";
    private static final String RUN = "java ";

    private static final String IO_ERROR_MESSAGE = "An I/O error has occured.";

    private final String code;
    private final File codeFile;
    private final String className;

    private boolean isCompiled = false;

    /**
     * Creates a new <code>JavaCode</code> object.
     * 
     * @param code
     *            The source code.
     * @param className
     *            The name of the <code>public</code> class
     */
    public JavaCode(String code, String className) {
        this.code = code;
        this.className = className;
        this.codeFile = new File(className + JAVA);
        try {
            // Delete any previous file with same name
            this.codeFile.delete();
            this.codeFile.createNewFile();
            writeCodeToFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println(IO_ERROR_MESSAGE);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        codeFile.deleteOnExit();
        new File(className + CLASS).deleteOnExit();
    }

    private void writeCodeToFile() throws IOException {
        try (BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(
                this.codeFile))) {
            writer.write(this.code);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Gets the source code of the object.
     * 
     * <p>
     * Equivalent to {@link #toString()}.
     * </p>
     * 
     * @return the source code
     * 
     * @see #toString()
     */
    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the class name of the source code.
     * 
     * @return the class name of the source code
     */
    public String getClassName() {
        return className;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     * 
     * Equivalent to {@link #getCode()}.
     * 
     * @return the source code
     * 
     * @see #toString()
     */
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getCode();
    }

    /**
     * Runs the source code using the command line.
     * 
     * <p>
     * Runs the program by first creating a new file named
     * <code>classname.java</code>, replacing <code>classname</code> with
     * whatever the class is named, executing <code>javac classname.java</code>,
     * then <code>java classname</code>.
     * </p>
     * 
     * <p>
     * It will delete the <code>.java</code> and <code>.class</code> files on
     * exit of program.
     * </p>
     */
    public void run() {
        try {
            if (!isCompiled) {
                ProcessInfo info = runProcess(COMPILE + this.className + JAVA);
                if (info.exitCode == 0) {
                    isCompiled = true;
                } else {
                    // Compiler error
                    System.err.print(info.errorMessage);
                    return;
                }
            }
            runProcess(RUN + this.className);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println(IO_ERROR_MESSAGE);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private ProcessInfo runProcess(String command) throws IOException,
            InterruptedException {
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        System.out.print(getLines(process.getInputStream()));
        process.waitFor();
        return new ProcessInfo(process.exitValue(),
                getLines(process.getErrorStream()));
    }

    private String getLines(InputStream instream) throws IOException {
        String line = null;
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(instream));
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            result.append(line).append('\n');
        }
        return result.toString();
    }

    private class ProcessInfo {

        private final int exitCode;
        private final String errorMessage;

        private ProcessInfo(int exitCode, String errorMessage) {
            this.exitCode = exitCode;
            this.errorMessage = errorMessage;
        }

    }

}
```

As an example, I ran a simple "Hello, World!" program and another (not-so-simple) [Project Euler #1](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/74566/project-euler-1-in-java) that I wrote.

Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new JavaCode("public class Main{public static void main(String[]args){System.out.println(\"Hello, World!\");}}", "Main").run();
    new JavaCode("public class MultipleFinder {private static final int MAX_NUMBER = 1000;private static final int[] MULTIPLES = new int[] { 3, 5 };public static void main(String[] args) {long time = System.nanoTime();int sum = 0;for(int multiple : MULTIPLES) {sum += triangle((MAX_NUMBER - 1) / multiple) * multiple;}sum -= triangle((MAX_NUMBER - 1) / (MULTIPLES[0] * MULTIPLES[1])) * (MULTIPLES[0] * MULTIPLES[1]);System.out.println(\"Result: \" + sum + \"\\nTime used for calculation in nanoseconds: \" + (System.nanoTime() - time));}private static int triangle(int i) {return (i + 1) * i / 2;}}", "MultipleFinder").run();
}
```

Note that I just put it on one line: I was too lazy to format it right.

The result makes sense (hover over to see the results; it is hidden for those that haven't solved Project Euler #1 yet):

> Hello, World!
>  Result: 233168
>  Time used for calculation in nanoseconds: 34486

Concerns:

1. Is there a simpler way to do what I did here?
2. Anything in the `java.nio` package that can make my life easier?
3. Is JavaDoc okay?
4. And as usual, anything else?

Some notes:

- The program may be ran multiple times. If this was the case, I would already have a compiled class file ready to be ran, therefore making it faster.

Comment: Is it a requirement to produce a .java file and a .class file? Or is your main goal to run some Java source code?

Comment: @200_success My main goal is to run java source code. I just realised that  forgot to make the files "delete on exit"...

Answer (score 5):

Here:

```
    codeFile.deleteOnExit();
    new File(className + CLASS).deleteOnExit();
```

This does not actually delete all the files. Consider this example code:

```
public class Foo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Bar.sayHi();
    }
}

class Bar {
    void sayHi() {
        System.out.println("hi");
    }
}
```

The program will delete the `.java` file, but will not delete the `Bar.class` file. Leaving a mess was not what I intended.

Answer (score 3):

If your main goal is just to run some Java code, then you might be better off [doing everything in memory](//stackoverflow.com/q/31599427/1157100) using the Java Compiler API.  Nothing needs to get written to disk.

I would expect it to be faster, but it's a lot more code to write, though.